# Javascript Sherlock Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Problem Statement

Watson gives Sherlock an array A of length N. Then he asks him to determine if there exists an element in the array such that the sum of the elements on its left is equal to the sum of the elements on its right. If there are no elements to the left/right, then the sum is considered to be zero. Formally, find an i, such that,
A1+A2...Ai−1=Ai+1+Ai+2...AN.
Input Format

The first line contains T, the number of test cases. For each test case, the first line contains N, the number of elements in the array A. The second line for each test case contains N space-separated integers, denoting the array A.

Output Format

For each test case print YES if there exists an element in the array, such that the sum of the elements on its left is equal to the sum of the elements on its right; otherwise print NO.

Constraints

1≤T≤10

1≤N≤105

1≤Ai≤2×104

1≤i≤N

Sample Input

2

3

1 2 3

4

1 2 3 3

Sample Output

NO

YES

Explanation

For the first test case, no such index exists. For the second test case,

A[1]+A[2]=A[4]

therefore index 3 satisfies the given conditions.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It looks like you just copy-pasted your task. StackOverflow is not a "do-my-homework" web-site.

Comment: It looks like homework to me, and that's clearly not what this site is for.  This is for helping resolve issues with your code - not write it for you.  Come back when you have something yourself.  I just googled and found dozens of answers.  You've literally not even done that.

Comment: By the way, the problem is absolutely simple. You need no knowledge except for basic arrays and loops to make a quadratic solution. Still, there is a smarter linear one.

Comment: *we believe that part of what makes a good engineer is writing code*

Answer (score 2):

This solution features [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

with a callback like

```
function isSherlock(_, i, a) {
    function sum(i, n) {
        return i < n ? a[i] + sum(i + 1, n) : 0;
    }
    return sum(0, i) === sum(i + 1, a.length);
}
```

where just the comparison is returned between the left side and the right side of the index, as well as it's recursive function

```
function sum(i, n) {
    return i < n ? a[i] + sum(i + 1, n) : 0;
}
```

for counting the array values with the index smaller than the given value.

Alltogether as working example:

```js
function isSherlock(_, i, a) {
    function sum(i, n) {
        return i < n ? a[i] + sum(i + 1, n) : 0;
    }
    return sum(0, i) === sum(i + 1, a.length);
}

document.write([1, 2, 3].some(isSherlock) + '<br>');
document.write([1, 2, 3, 3].some(isSherlock) + '<br>');
```